# My code doesn't recognize negative numbers

Tags: c++

i have wrote a code that say condition of Water.but it doesn't work with negative numbers

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int a;
cin >> a;
if (a > 100){
cout << "Steam";
}else if (0 <= a <= 100){
cout << "Water";}else if(a < 0){cout << "Ice";}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `(0 <= a <= 100)` should be `(0 <= a && a <= 100)` voting to close as a typo.

Comment: Just do what @TedLyngmo said ... also please look into indentation (coz code looks a bit ugly)

Answer (score 3):

The condition `0 <= a <= 100` is treated as `(0 <= a) <= 100`.

`0 <= a` will be evaluated as 0 or 1 according to the comparision result, so it will always be less than 100.

You should use a condition `0 <= a && a <= 100` instead.

Comment: Thank you.now i get it

Answer (score 0):

`0 <= a <= 100` is incorrect. For multiple comparisons use `0 <= a && a <= 100`